# Android picture only permission

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

My application is using the camera only to take picture.
I'm using Android SDK 29 with flutter.

I use the permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

The trouble is that it asks the user if he allows the application to use the mic to record audio. I guess it comes from the fact that it can be videos. Is it possible to remove this mic permission that is totally useless for my app ?

My guess is that it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using camera-0.5.7 dependency, I have to initialize my camera controller as following:

```
_controller = CameraController(
  widget.camera,
  ResolutionPreset.medium,
  enableAudio: false
);
```

Once you do this, I don't even need to remove the permission from the AndroidManifest.xml and the Audio Recording Permission is not asked.

Answer (score 2):

**I guess it comes from the fact that it can be videos** : I don't think so, maybe you're using some libs requires some permissions to work, however, try to remove the unnecessary permissions as follows :

**Your Flutter Project > android > app > src > main > AndroidManifest.xml** and add :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Comment: I'll try this, and mark it as an answer if it works

Comment: It doesn't work : /, I can't even use anymore my camera